# How to use ndcg metric for binary relevance

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, ranking, learning-to-rank, text-classification

I am working on a ranking problem to predict the right single document based on the user query and use the NDCG metric to measure the model.

**Given the details :**

Queries ( Q ), Result Document ( D ), Relevance score. 
But the relevance score is a binary ( 0 or 1 ) i.e out of document lists, only one document is marked as relevance score =1.

**Data set example:**

```
 query, docs,relevance
{
[1, doc2,0],[1, doc3,0],[1, doc4,0 ],[1, doc6,1],[1, doc9,0]
[2, doc3,0],[2, doc5,1],[2, doc10,0],[2, doc11,0],[2, doc1,0]
}
```

**My questions:**
1. Is it possible to use the NDCG metric for binary relevance problems?
2. If so, please share some reading notes or suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The nDCG depends on the relevance of each document as you can see on the Wikipedia [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain). I guess you could use 0 and 1 as relevance scores, but then all relevant documents would have the same score of 1, and then it wouldn't make much sense to apply the nDCG penalty discounts.

A similar measure often used with binary relevance scores is the mean average precision defined as:

$\text{MAP}=\frac{\sum_{q=1}^Q\text{AveP}(q)}{Q}$,

where $Q$ is the number of queries.

A comprehensive explanation of both nDCG and MAP is available [here](https://medium.com/swlh/rank-aware-recsys-evaluation-metrics-5191bba16832)